# How to smooth an array 1000x1000 quickly

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

We are simulating a sedimentation in a French bay (Mont Saint Michel), for this, we are putting sediments (represented as numbers) in an array. 
The deposit is random in our 1000x1000 array, with an island in the middle.

At the end of the program, we d like to smooth our bay everywhere apart from the island where the numbers are equal to zero.

We did it, but it s far too long to run.. Can someone help us to find a way to accelerate our program ?

```
for j in range (0,375):
    for decale in range (250): 

        diff=M[749+decale][j]-M[749+decale+1][j] 
        if diff>=3: 
            M[749+decale][j]-=floor(19*diff/20) 
            M[749+decale+1][j]+=floor(19*diff/20)

for j in range (625,1000):  #for the S-W of the bay
    for decale in range (250): 

        diff=M[749+decale][j]-M[749+decale+1][j] 
        if diff>=3:
            M[749+decale][j]-=floor(19*diff/20) 
            M[749+decale+1][j]+=floor(19*diff/20) 

for i in range (800,1000):


    for decale in range (799): For the West of the bay

        diff=M[i][200+decale]-M[i][200+decale+1]
        if diff>=3: 
            M[i][200+decale]-=floor(19*diff/20) 
            M[i][200+decale+1]+=floor(19*diff/20)

    for decale in range (799): #Idem

        diff=M[i][799-decale]-M[i][799-decale-1] 
        if diff>=3: 
            M[i][799-decale]-=floor(19*diff/20) 
            M[i][799-decale-1]+=floor(19*diff/20) 

for j in range (0,375): #Along the island
    for decale in range (350):
        diff=M[850-decale][j]-M[850-decale-1][j] 
        if diff>=3: 
            M[850-decale][j]-=floor(19*diff/20)
            M[850-decale-1][j]+=floor(19*diff/20) 

for j in range(625,1000): #Idem
    for decale in range (350):
        diff=M[850-decale][j]-M[850-decale-1][j] 
        if diff>=3: 
            M[850-decale][j]-=floor(19*diff/20) 
            M[850-decale-1][j]+=floor(19*diff/20)

for i in range (500,549): #Idem
    for decale in range (500): 

        diff=M[i][499+decale]-M[i][499+decale+1] 
        if diff>=3:
            M[i][499+decale]-=floor(19*diff/20) 
            M[i][499+decale+1]+=floor(19*diff/20) 

    for decale in range (500):  #Idem

        diff=M[i][500-decale]-M[i][500-decale-1] 
        if diff>=3: 
            M[i][500-decale]-=floor(19*diff/20)   
            M[i][500-decale-1]+=floor(19*diff/20) 

return M
```

Comment: what does *smooth* mean in the context of your application?

Comment: is there any chance you would consider using Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything about the correctness of these loops. I just translated them into Numpy array, so it can be a bit more readable.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array(M)

diff = M[749:-1,:375]-M[750:,:375]
M[749:-1,:375][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[750:  ,:375][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[749:-1,625:]-M[750:,625:] # for the S-W of the bay
M[749:-1,625:][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[750:  ,625:][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[800:,200:-1]-M[800:,201:] # for the West of the bay
M[800:,200:-1][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[800:,201:  ][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[800:,1:800]-M[800:,:799] #Idem 
M[800:,1:800][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[800:, :799][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[501:851,:375]-M[500:850,:375] #Along the island
M[501:851,:375][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[500:850,:375][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[501:851,625:]-M[500:850,625:] #Idem
M[501:851,625:][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[500:850,625:][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[500:549,499:-2]-M[500:549,500:-1] #Idem
M[500:549,499:-2][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[500:549,500:-1][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)

diff = M[500:549,1:501]-M[500:549,:500] #Idem
M[500:549,1:501][diff>=3] -= np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
M[500:549,:500][diff>=3] += np.floor(19*diff[diff>=3]/20)
```